# How can I initialize an array of pointers pointing to a struct?

Tags: c

I have the following struct:

```
struct clientDetails 
{
    int socket;  
    char* port;
    char* IP;
    char* hostName;
    int msgSentCount;
    int msgRecvCount;
    char* status;
    char bufferMsg[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char blockedUser[4];
    int blockedCount;   
};
```

And I have an array of pointers:

```
struct clientDetails* allClients[4];
```

How can I initialize all the array elements of allClients to have default values?

I have tried the following but I am getting 'incomplete definition of type struct':

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        allClients[i]->socket = 0;  
        allClients[i]->port = NULL;
        allClients[i]->IP = NULL;
        allClients[i]->hostName = NULL;
        allCLients[i]->msgSentCount = 0;
        allClients[i]->msgRecvCount = 0;    
        allClients[i]->status = NULL;
        allClients[i]->bufferMsg = "";
        allClients[i]->blockedUser = {"","","",""};
        allClients[i]->blockedCount = 0;    
}
```

Comment: On what line is the error? Provide a [minimal self-containing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can initialize a pointer by making it point to something. BTW: Are you using a C++compiler?

Comment: Yes. I am using gcc.

Comment: This: 'allClients[i]->blockedUser = {"","","",""};' is initializing with four empty strings rather than four chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you need to allocate storage for that struct... right now all you have a single pointer.  Right at the top of your loop, you should do something like:

```
allClients[i] = malloc(sizeof(clientDetails));
```

It's been a while since I've done structs in "C", but you could/should probably `typedef` your struct as well.

Comment: Actually, if you use calloc (instead of malloc) all this initialization in your case is done for you.